# Запуск функции из основного файла в модуле

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, импорт

Допустим у меня в основном коде есть функция:

```
def func1(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

И есть второй файл с названием `file2.py`.
Как мне из файла `file2.py` вызвать функцию `func1`?
(Мне нужно импортировать 2 файл в основном коде, и через функцию во втором файле вызвать функцию `func1`).
Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Comment: 2 файл это что то типо модуля, в котором есть полезные плюшки для облегчения программирования

Comment: from file1 import func1 вы про это?

Comment: `file2.txt` — txt ? Не `.py` ?

Comment: py, в нём есть функция, которую можно запустить через 1 файл, и она запустит какую-либо функцию из 1 файла (вызванная функция из второго файла вызывает функцию из основного файла)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  Извините, перепутал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file2.py**

```
a = 10
b = 20

def call(fn): # Получив любую функцию в виде аргумента,
    fn(a, b)  # вызовет её с аргументами (a, b)
```

**file1.py**

```
import file2

def func1(x, y):
    print(x, y)

file2.call(func1) # Передаем ожидаемый аргумент (функцию).
# 10 20
```

---

В примере функции ничего не возвращают, но могли бы:

**file2.py**

```
a = 10
b = 20

def call(fn):
    return fn(a, b)
```

**file1.py**

```
import file2

def func1(x, y):
    return x + y

result = file2.call(func1)
print(result) # 30
```